# how to access Apple Remote Desktop (ARD) via VNC-over-SSH?

Tags: macos, ssh, remote-desktop, apple-remote-desktop

I've done a bit of research and it seems ARD is somewhat based on VNC technology. It even has the option to allow access via VNC viewers using a password.

I want to enable this option so I can interact with my mac pro when needed. But I'm wary of the security.

I've use VNC-over-SSH in the past but with other OSes like FreeBSD and Linux. I'm wondering if something like this is feasible on OSX using ***built-in*** features.

I've searched the net but didn't find what I'm looking for.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Do you want to uncover the full features of ARD or just "VNC Viewing"? Just VNC could be easily done via ssh port forwarding any port to port 5900. Apple uses the same port for screen sharing as VNC does.

Comment: I want to interact with the MacPro via VNC on my android phone like when using the remote desktop client on my MBPr. thanks again

Comment: *"I want to enable this option so I can interact with my mac pro when needed. But I'm wary of the security."* +1. ARD has an 8-character password limitation (based in its VNC roots). Its a bad idea to expose ARD directly to the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can.  If you open System Preferences > Sharing, and check both remote management (to start the vnc server) and remote login (to start the ssh server); you should be able to login remotely using vnc over ssh.

Note: You must have all needed ports forwarded correctly, and an android client capable of connecting over ssh.